# Calculate percentage against total for a specified condition (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sum, aggregate-functions

I am working on a query that's supposed to return a data set that will be consumed by a report. Suppose i have a table `dbo.payments` with data as shown below:

```
-----------------------------------------------
Customer |Commission| Trade Date | Trade Type | 
-----------------------------------------------
AMIRALIS | 20.00    | 22/01/2018 |   SALE     |
BRUSSASH | 30.00    | 22/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
AMIRALIS | 10.00    | 22/01/2018 |   SALE     |
AKBMOBIL | 50.00    | 22/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
AMIRALIS | 10.00    | 23/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
BRUSSASH | 10.00    | 23/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
BRUSSASH | 30.00    | 23/01/2018 |   SALE     |
BRUSSASH | 10.00    | 23/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
AMIRALIS | 60.00    | 24/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
BRUSSASH | 10.00    | 24/01/2018 |   SALE     |
```

Scenario #1: I want to write a query that will give me the results as shown below. Please not that the percentage is against the `SUM(Commission)` of all time `240.00` regardless of the where clause.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Customer |Total Commission| Trade Date |%Commission | 
-----------------------------------------------------
AMIRALIS |     30.00      | 22/01/2018 |  0.125     |
BRUSSASH |     30.00      | 22/01/2018 |  0.125     |
AKBMOBIL |     50.00      | 22/01/2018 |  0.208     |
AMIRALIS |     10.00      | 23/01/2018 |  0.041     |
BRUSSASH |     50.00      | 23/01/2018 |  0.208     |
AMIRALIS |     60.00      | 24/01/2018 |  0.250     |
BRUSSASH |     10.00      | 24/01/2018 |  0.041     |
```

Am a SQL newbie, the furthest i could go was:.

`SELECT [TRADE DATE] AS DATE, CUSTOMER, SUM([COMMISSION]) AS TOTAL, ([COMMISSION] / (SELECT SUM([COMMISSION]) FROM DBO.PAYMENTS)) AS '%COMMISSION' FROM DBO.PAYMENTS GROUP BY [TRADE DATE], CUSTOMER, COMMISSION`

How to i achieve the desired result, regardlessor the WHERE clause:i.e. `WHERE [Trade Date] BETWEEN '21/01/2018' AND '24/01/2018'` which reduces the total to `170.00`

Comment: As written, your question is too broad.  I would suggest you ask a question about *one* of the scenarios.

Comment: sure, i think i can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be solved using SQL Server window functions, like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.Customer,
    SUM(t.Commission) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Trade_Date) Total_Commission,
    t.Trade_Date,
     SUM(t.Commission) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Trade_Date) / SUM(t.Commission) OVER() "%Commission"
FROM mytable t 
ORDER BY 1, 3
```

**[Demo on DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8bc641595aabb64a9150724e377c3b7)** :

```
 Customer | Total_Commission | Trade_Date          | %Commission
 :------- | :--------------- | :------------------ | :----------
 AKBMOBIL | 50.00            | 22/01/2018 00:00:00 | 0.208333   
 AMIRALIS | 30.00            | 22/01/2018 00:00:00 | 0.125000   
 AMIRALIS | 10.00            | 23/01/2018 00:00:00 | 0.041666   
 AMIRALIS | 60.00            | 24/01/2018 00:00:00 | 0.250000   
 BRUSSASH | 30.00            | 22/01/2018 00:00:00 | 0.125000   
 BRUSSASH | 50.00            | 23/01/2018 00:00:00 | 0.208333   
 BRUSSASH | 10.00            | 24/01/2018 00:00:00 | 0.041666
```

PS : if you need to filter the output by date, you can simply add a `WHERE` clause to the query. This will filter both computations.

Comment: putting the where clause will affect the currently calculated total. The desired percentage is against the total of all records regardless of the filter

Comment: Accepted this answer because it's the closest to what I wanted to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregation query.  In this case, you can use a window function to calculate the total commission:

```
select Customer, TradeDate,
       sum(Commission) as total_Commission,
       sum(Commission) / sum(sum(Commission)) over () as percent_commission
from dbo.payments p
group by Customer, TradeDate
```

Comment: If i put a where clause, the total reduces to that specified in the where clause. What i want is against the total of all time.

Comment: @TakudzwaMawarire . . . Your question specifies that adding the `where` clause reduces the total.  That implies that you want the filtering.

Comment: the question had said "How to i achieve the desired result, regardless of the WHERE clause". Sorry if my question wasn't clear but that is what i was trying to explain.