# Calculate percentage value for each row based on calculated total in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that's supposed to return a data set that will be consumed by a report. Suppose i have a table `dbo.payments` with data as shown below:

```
-----------------------------------------------
Customer |Commission| Trade Date | Trade Type | 
-----------------------------------------------
AMIRALIS | 20.00    | 22/01/2018 |   SALE     |
BRUSSASH | 30.00    | 22/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
AMIRALIS | 10.00    | 22/01/2018 |   SALE     |
AKBMOBIL | 50.00    | 22/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
AMIRALIS | 10.00    | 23/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
BRUSSASH | 10.00    | 23/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
BRUSSASH | 30.00    | 23/01/2018 |   SALE     |
BRUSSASH | 10.00    | 23/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
AMIRALIS | 60.00    | 24/01/2018 |  PURCHASE  |
BRUSSASH | 10.00    | 24/01/2018 |   SALE     |
```

I want to return the percentage against the total for the specified period. Say `WHERE [Trade Date] BETWEEN '21/01/2018' AND '24/01/2018'` total = `170.00`

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Customer |Total Commission| Trade Date |%Commission | 
-----------------------------------------------------
AMIRALIS |     30.00      | 22/01/2018 |  0.176     |
BRUSSASH |     30.00      | 22/01/2018 |  0.176     |
AKBMOBIL |     50.00      | 22/01/2018 |  0.294     |
AMIRALIS |     10.00      | 23/01/2018 |  0.059     |
BRUSSASH |     50.00      | 23/01/2018 |  0.294     |
```

Am a SQL newbie, the furthest i could go to return the desired result was:.

```
SELECT [TRADE DATE] AS DATE, CUSTOMER, SUM([COMMISSION]) AS TOTAL, ([COMMISSION] / SUM([COMMISSION])) AS '%COMMISSION' FROM DBO.PAYMENTS GROUP BY [TRADE DATE], CUSTOMER, COMMISSION
```

and am not getting the desired outcome.

Also, the WHERE clause to the query i.e. `... WHERE DATE BETWEEN '21/01/2018' AND '24/01/2018'` specifying the date range is appended by the report after the user selects the desired dates.

How do i return the percentage against the total for the specified period ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would just add a `where` clause to your original query (which is the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392985/calculate-percentage-against-total-for-a-specified-condition-sql-server))

```
select Customer, TradeDate,
       sum(Commission) as total_Commission,
       sum(Commission) / sum(sum(Commission)) over () as percent_commission
where TradeDate >= '2018-01-21' and
      TradeDate < '2018-01-24'
from dbo.payments p
group by Customer, TradeDate;
```

Notes:

- Date constants should always use YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD formats.  These are ISO 8601 standards accepted by almost all databases.
- Don't use `BETWEEN` with dates.  [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is a very good explanation by Aaron Bertrand.
- If `commission` is an integer, then you need a non-integer for the division.  I often just add `* 1.0` before the `/`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `CTE` like following.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT customer, 
                commission, 
                [trade date], 
                [trade type], 
                Sum(commission) OVER() tot 
         FROM   dbo.payment 
         WHERE  [trade date] > '21/01/2018' 
                AND [trade date] < '24/01/2018') 
SELECT *, 
       commission * 100.0 / tot AS [%Commission] 
FROM   cte
```

Comment: `tot` would be a running total in your code since you have an `order by` in your `over` clause.

Comment: You are right @ZoharPeled, I just realized that. Thank you for pointing this. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use `sum` with an empty `over` clause to get the total sum of commission selected by the query. This way, you don't have to worry about the where clause:

```
SELECT  [TRADE DATE] AS DATE, 
        CUSTOMER, 
        COMMISSION,
        CAST(COMMISSION as float) / SUM([COMMISSION]) OVER() AS '%COMMISSION', 
FROM DBO.PAYMENTS 
WHERE ...
```

Also, please note the cast of the `COMMISSION` to float (assumed it's an int). If you divide int with another int, you'll get an integer division which will never return a decimal.